# How to make textArea handle multiple events the same?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I want to make my text area handle `onCut`, `onPaste`, `onKeydown` and `onKeyup` the same. I.e. they all affect the textArea the same.

I am creating the javascript as a `string` and using it within `Codeigniter`.

Currently, in my code below, none of the functions are working when all together, How can I fix this?

Note: when the code is only:

```
$javascript= 'onKeyDown || onKeyUp="exampleFunction()"';
```

It works fine, but **doesn't** work with:

```
$javascript= 'onKeyDown || onKeyUp || onPaste || onCut="exampleFunction()"';
```

Where javascript being called:

```
echo form_textarea('text',0,$javascript);
```

Comment: How can this code ever work? Can you show us an entire page? Where are you rendering this string?

Comment: please see edit at bottom