# PHP/CodeIgniter: Place elements on the same line?

Tags: php, codeigniter, input, label

I am using `code igniter` in order to generate elements. I want to have a `form label` and an `input box` on the **same** line.

However currently the input box is displayed **below** the label.

How can I ensure that the input box is on the **same line** as the label, and to its right.

```
<?php

echo form_label('Age: ','age');

echo form_input('userAge',"");

?>
```

Comment: Probably something like this `echo form_label('Age: '.form_input('userAge',""),'age');`

Comment: where is your source for this? tried but not working thanks

Comment: What do you mean by not working? can you provide the HTML output of what you tried and then the output of my suggestion. My source is my brain.

Comment: Sorry, it is now working thanks, however I need a space between the two also, how can I do so? thanks

Comment: My example does provide a space. If you need to force additional spaces then try this `echo form_label('Age:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.form_input('userAge',""),'age');`

Comment: How can I ensure that the input box is readonly?

Comment: Do you know how to make a text area respond to onpaste and oncut the same way as it does for onkeydown and onkeyup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565396/javscript-how-to-make-textarea-handle-multiple-events-the-same I have not got an answer for that yet

Comment: It's do-able but I would not recommend it because it produces inline Javascript and will be horrific to maintain in the future. Another issue is that all of these function calls will add up over time. Each call may take only 1 millisecond in additional processing time but multiply those milliseconds by the number of function calls and then again by the expected amount of visitors and before you know it you will be switching back to plain HTML

Comment: can you show me how, I will accept answer on other question then if working

Comment: The functionality of `form_textarea()` is identical to `form_input()`. I am sure you can figure it out based on the answer I provided. Good luck

Comment: I am referring to the other question, i.e. how to get onpaste and oncut to work in the same function as onkeyup and onkeydown

Comment: That's a javascript issue, not a CodeIgniter one. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
echo form_label('Age: '.form_input('userAge',""),'age');
```

---

Based on your comments, this is how you force additional spaces:

```
echo form_label('Age:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.form_input('userAge',""),'age');
```

---

Based on your other comment:

```
echo form_label('Age:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.form_input(array('name'=>'userAge','value'=>'johndoe','readonly'=>'readonly')),'age');
```

---

**For more information you should read through:**

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html